# Text before the table automatically moves to the previous page

Tags: tables, page-breaking

I want to create an appendix at the end of my text. The problem is that the text in the appendix ("We present results") is moving to the previous page while the table remains in the same position. On the pages before the appendix I have tables. here is what I use (Please, help me to resolve this issue):

```
\setcounter{table}{0}

\newpage
\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendices}

\section{Appendix for ...}\label{int}

We present results

\begin{table}[h]
....
```

In the page before I have tables such as:

```
\newpage
\centering

\begin{table}[!ht] 
....
```

EXAMPLE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[mincitenames=1,maxcitenames=2,authordate,giveninits=true, 
backend=biber, natbib]{biblatex-chicago}
%\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber, natbib]{biblatex-chicago}


\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% package for including graphics with figure-environment
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{breqn}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\addbibresource{Reference.bib}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup{justification   = raggedright,
          singlelinecheck = false}



\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}
%\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[left=2.54cm,top=2.54cm,right=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\cfoot[]{\pagemark} 
\setheadsepline[122mm]{0.3mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
 %
\doublespacing
\makeatletter
\def\@xfootnote[#1]{%
\protected@xdef\@thefnmark{#1}%
\@footnotemark\@footnotetext}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\newpage
\centering

\begin{table}[hbt!] 
\caption{Estimation }

\label{table:changes-ucons}
  \bigskip
  \centering
\begin{threeparttable}
  \footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc} \hline

 &\multicolumn{2}{c}{C} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{T} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{No T}  
\\

 \cmidrule[0.4pt](r{0.125em}){2-3}% 
 \cmidrule[0.4pt](r{0.125em}){4-5}% 
\cmidrule[0.4pt](r{0.125em}){6-7}%

VARIABLES  & x & y & x & y & x & y \\ \hline
  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\

$abc$ & -0.451*** &-0.331**  &-0.505***  &-0.377***  &-0.465***  &-0.618***  
\\
   & (-5.386) &(-3.161)  &(-7.127)  &(-4.837)  &(-9.773)  &(-6.085)  \\



  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\

  Observations & 228 & 28 & 349 & 36 & 2,850 & 218 \\

  Clustered St. Errors & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\ \hline
  \hline
   \end{tabular}


  \end{threeparttable}
  \end{table}


 \newpage

 \setcounter{table}{0}
 %\appendix
 %\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendices}

  \section{Internet Appendix}
  \label{internet}

  We present results...

 \begin{table}[!htbp] 
 \caption{Estimation of corporate insiders' profitability}

\centering
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\bigskip
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{lccc}
        \hline   

        VARIABLES & All Trades & Purchase Trades & Sales Trades \\ \hline
        &  &  &     \\
         Profit &0.008*** &0.083***&-0.009*** \\
        & (6.845) &(26.205) &(-7.952) \\

        &&&\\

        N & 171452 &31276 & 140176 \\ \hline \hline
    \end{tabular}

   \end{threeparttable}
  \end{table}



  \end{document}
```

Comment: Please extend you example to a [full but minimal document](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that produces the output you encounter

Comment: it is hard to tell from so little information but most likely the `\newpage` before `\appendix` should be `\clearpage` to stop floats coming past.

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion worked perfectly! The only thing, now the name of the section stay apart like "Internet                               Appendix". Smth like this. Is there is a way to correct this?